# Webform simplenews component styling

Tags: theming, emails

I am creating a Newsletter field for just one component to include email only for newsletter subscription, but I need a way to style both the input field and the submit button to be inline, i.e side by side rather than above each other like typical forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [arrange fields module](https://drupal.org/project/arrange_fields).

> This module lets you drag-and-drop the fields of any CCK content type,
>   Webform, or almost any other form in Drupal into the positions you
>   would like for editing. This makes it super simple to have forms with
>   inline fields, which you can change at any point. Tab indexing is also
>   updated, so no matter how you arrange the fields, the users can still
>   tab through them easily. And, you can now add arbitrary bits of HTML
>   markup-- labels, images, HR's, etc.